# Problems with accessing AD Information (PowerShell Script works, C# code dont)

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, adsi

I found this PowerShell Script that searches for Exchange Servers in the Domain.

```
    Function Get-ExchangeServerInSite {
    $ADSite = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySite]
    $siteDN = $ADSite::GetComputerSite().GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedName
    $configNC=([ADSI]"LDAP://RootDse").configurationNamingContext
    $search = new-object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"LDAP://$configNC")
    $objectClass = "objectClass=msExchExchangeServer"
    $site = "msExchServerSite=$siteDN"
    $search.Filter = "(&($objectClass)($site))"
    $search.PageSize=1000
    [void] $search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
    [void] $search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msexchcurrentserverroles")
    [void] $search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("networkaddress")
    $search.FindAll() | %{
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Name = $_.Properties.name[0]
            FQDN = $_.Properties.networkaddress |
                %{if ($_ -match "ncacn_ip_tcp") {$_.split(":")[1]}}
            Roles = $_.Properties.msexchcurrentserverroles[0]
        }
    }
}

    $role = @{
    2  = "MB"
    4  = "CAS"
    16 = "UM"
    32 = "HT"
    64 = "ET"
}


   foreach ($server in Get-ExchangeServerinSite) {
  $roles = ($role.keys | ?{$_ -band $server.roles} | %{$role.Get_Item($_)}) -join ", "
  $server | select Name, @{n="Roles";e={$roles}},FQDN
}
```

Because I need the same task in C# code without using PowerShell. I tried using the .Net classes the same way and even debuged both scripts and the info is the same.

Now my problem. The PowerShell script correctly displays the server and the C# code returns an empty collection.

Here is the C#

```
string siteDN = ActiveDirectorySite.GetComputerSite().GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();

DirectoryEntry RootDSE = new DirectoryEntry( @"LDAP://RootDSE" );
string baseStr = @"LDAP://" + RootDSE.Properties["configurationNamingContext"].Value ;

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(baseStr ); 

string classObj = "objectClass=msExchExchangeServer";
string site = "msExchServerSite="+siteDN;
searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&({0})({1}))",classObj,site);

searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "name" );
searcher.PageSize = 1000;
searcher.ServerTimeLimit = new TimeSpan(0,1,0);
searcher.CacheResults = false;

SearchResultCollection coll = searcher.FindAll();
```

The only difference I could find was the `[ADSI]` tag in the PowerShell code but I couldn't find out what the C# part is from that.

Comment: Another point: the Powershell code adds **three** properties to be loaded to the `DirectorySearcher` - your C# code adds only one of those.

Comment: yeah but it does not matter how many properties will be loaded, because the property array lets you define which information is interesting, and for me its only the name.

Comment: try removing the `ServerTimeLimit` - maybe that just kicks in and then no results are returned...

Comment: I got it now. The Pendant is to create a new DirectoryEntry from baseStr.. and give it to the DirectorySearcher instead of directly passing the baseStr.